# Order of procedure for connecting containers in SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to learn SSIS to create SharePoint packages for our company site. Through trial and error, I have learned to create basic packages that will extract specific data from existing SP source lists and populate others.

I found basic information on the web that has helped me thus far. Unfortunately, I cannot find information on an order of procedure for effectively using some of the SSIS containers

As an example, I know that a SP List Source must be followed by a Sort before a Merge Join Transformation. However, I am uncertain if a Derived Column should precede a Conditional Split, or if it really matters. Additionally, there are 2 connection points on Derived Column and Conditional Split containers, one Red and the other Blue. I assume they are used to connect a Derived Column to multiple Conditional Split containers, or vice versa, but I really don’t know for certain.

Can anyone help by providing me with a web source that doesn’t just tell me what a container does, but how to use it effectively. I’m ready for the next steps, but I don’t have reliable connections to get the information I need. BTW... I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SP 2013.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be given.

Comment: _if a Derived Column should precede a Conditional Split_ If your conditional split requires the derived column then it needs to go before. Otherwise it doesn't matter. With regards to red and blue, red is always an error indicator - your errors come out of here. Blue is one (of possibly many) conditional split data flows. I suggest you just experiment and test